# Ubuntu 11.04 not booting

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, ubuntu-11.04

I installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04, I usually got the problem with Ubuntu for first boot. When the bootloader comes up, I chose the Ubuntu, but it stayed still, it didn't go into the system. Could you please give me any solution about that?

Answer (score 0):

***Could you please give me any solution about that?***

I find Grub2 and Windows 7's boot loader seem to not mix that well for now... The solution I tend to find gets me back on track fast is to install ["EasyBCD" for Windows](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1). You'll want to run it as your main bootloader. It provides a very easy to edit boot menu (edit in Windows).

If you're still having problems getting Linux to boot at all, take a look at using [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub-disk/) to at least get back in there.